# How to retrieve the date records based on today's date in C# and MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

I want to select the records where the `dateTimefield` is equal to today's date.  The DBMS is MySQL.

Comment: See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Please remember to give tables names — it makes it easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE(dateTimefield) = CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Is this any more index friendly?  :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Ha! Good point.  I suppose `WHERE dateTimefield BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY` would be better?

Comment: Thank you now i got the records

Comment: Almost: the trouble with `a BETWEEN x AND y` is that the ranges are inclusive; it is equivalent to `a >= x AND z <= y`.  You'd need to exclude the end point: `WHERE dateTimeField >= CURRENT_DATE AND dateTimeField < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.  Of course, the whole issue of index friendliness only matters if the table is big enough that a sequential scan is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dateField,'%m-%d-%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y');
```